# error: invalid use of undefined type struct in C

Tags: c, function, struct, scope, malloc

I received this error compiling in C:

```
error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct block’
  blocks[0].i=1;
error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct block’
  blocks[0].j=1;
error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct block’
  blocks[0].k=1;
```

here my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void read_block(blocks);

int main()
{
        struct block
        {
                int i,j,k;
        } *blocks;

        blocks=malloc(sizeof(struct block));
        read_block(blocks);
        printf("primo val %d\n",blocks[0].i);
}
void read_block(struct block *blocks)
{
        blocks[0].i=1;
        blocks[0].j=2;
        blocks[0].k=3;


}

return(blocks);
}
```

Blocks are defined, and they should be a struct. So why the compiler cannot see them?

Comment: The scope of `struct block` is local to main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you defined  them inside `main()`, they  scope is just
`main()`. Outside of it, they don't exist. To fix this, move
the declaration:

```
struct block
{
    int i,j,k;
};

int main()
{
    struct block *blocks;
    /* ... */
```

Also note that you need to  declare the types in a parameter
list of a function declaration:

```
void read_block(blocks); /* bad */
void read_block(struct block *blocks);
```

Finally, there is an extra  `return` statement at the end of
your code that would prevent  this program from compiling. I
suppose this  is just a typo  when pasting the code  on this
question.

Comment: In the declaration i did what you suggest, or you mean when i call the function (line 13)?

Comment: @federicorovere In your line 3, the first declaration of `read_blocks`.

Answer (score 3):

It's about the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1,

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be
>   used) only within a region of program text called its scope. [...]

and

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [...]

You have defined `struct block` inside the `main()` function, so the scope is limited to that function (i.e., ends with the closing `}` of `main()`).

Outside `main()`, `struct block` does not have a valid definition. So, your compiler is complaining.

Move the declaration of `struct block` outside the `main()`, put it into file scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Each name that appears in a C++ program is only valid in some possibly
>   discontiguous portion of the source code called its scope. ([ISO/IEC 9899:2011](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope))

Basically, your `struct` is only visible within the `{}` it is enclosed in. In your case those brackets  are the one of the `main` function. Outside them, your structure does not exists.

Try something like the following:

```
struct block
{
   int i,j,k;
};
int main()
{
        block* blocks;

        blocks=malloc(sizeof(struct block));
        read_block(blocks);
        printf("primo val %d\n",blocks[0].i);
}
void read_block(struct block *blocks)
{
        blocks[0].i=1;
        blocks[0].j=2;
        blocks[0].k=3;


}

return(blocks);
}
```

Comment: It's surely nice to have standard references, however note that this question is about C and not C++.

Comment: @sidyll, fixed.